# Why do ions form condensation centres in isopropanol vapour?

Tags: physical-chemistry

In cloud chambers the particles are detected when a particle passes through the chamber causing the vapour to condense into a "cloud". What Process causes this observed phenomenon? In other words, how exactly do the particles tracks form in a cloud chamber?

Comment: Like I said, this is because ions attract neutral molecules. In the unstable supercooled vapor, this tiny perturbation is just enough to trigger the formation of a new phase. Then again, I appreciate your effort to verify the results of an experiment (that is, your question) by repeating it, but if you are expecting a different outcome this time around, don't.

Comment: Thx Ivan, I appreciate your answer. I repeated the question because the first time I posted it, it was downvoted as “off-topic” and removed. How is it off-topic???

Comment: Anyway, I’m keeping the question up (until it’s removed again) to garner more answers. I’m not a chemist (trained in physics); do you mind elucidating your answer a little more?

Comment: Dah... As I said before, the neutral molecules are [polarizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizability). Thus even though the whole molecules of the saturated vapor are not charged, the molecules can be attracted to ions in the vapor forming a nucleation center.

Comment: Thx Max. No need to say “dah.” I’m supposing that the molecules in the vapour polarize, and the positively charged end of each one thereupon bonds to the negative ion, created the trail, Is that about correct? As noted, I’m not a chemist.

Comment: Sounds about right. Note also that isopropanol molecules (as well as many others) are naturally polar, even if you don't polarize them.

Comment: Thx Ivan. Good to know I’m on the right track 